# Adjusting watermark according to video resolution using ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have a question related to video conversion I am trying to add watermark to different high resolution videos using `ffmpeg` and its getting added pretty fine but the issue is same watermark gets bigger on low resolution videos which was looking fine with high resolution video.Is there any possible way i can scale watermark according to video resolution?.I am sure there is but I seem to be pretty blank in this area any help regarding this issue would be really appreciated.

This is the command that i am using to add watermark in my php script

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/demo/files/conversion_queue/15490094394e7a7.mp4 -i /var/www/html/demo/upload/images/watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' -y /var/www/html/cb_corp_git/upload/files/conversion_queue/15490094394e7a7-wm.mp4
```

Comment: use the [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the scale2ref filter as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*5/100':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=10:10" output.mp4
```

This will proprortionally scale the watermark width to 5% of the video width, and then overlay the resized watermark.

Comment: Thanks Gyan for your response i will try it out in a while this seems like it will work